# how to control cs:go alias commands via python?

Tags: python, controls

There are commands in the x go console like "+forward", "+left" and so on. And to them I set alias example: Alias: +fr, Command: "+forward". How can I use python to control such commands in the game?

Maybe subprocces does it somehow, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

To control game commands like "+forward", "+left"..etc from a Python script, you can use the subprocess module to run the game console and send commands to it.

Comment: And it can happen in the background? While I'm in the browser it will run? And if you know roughly how to do it, could you give me a little hint with the code? I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: import subprocess
import time

def send_game_command(command):
    subprocess.Popen(['game_executable_path', '+set', command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Replace 'game_executable_path' with the actual path to your game executable.
# For example, 'C:\\Games\\YourGame\\game.exe' on Windows or '/home/user/games/yourgame' on Linux.

# Sending commands
send_game_command('+forward')
time.sleep(1)  # Wait for a second
send_game_command('+left')
time.sleep(1)
send_game_command('alias +fr +forward') -In this example code, we use the subprocess.Popen